# How to split a file that contain BigIntegers into 2 equal parts?

Tags: java, sorting, split, biginteger, java-io

I want to split a bigintegers file into 2 equal parts.

Here is I generate a file with random bigintegers

```
public void generateRandomBigInteger(){

    if(file.length() > 0){
        System.out.println("Sobreescriptura de fitxer no permesa!\n");
    }
    else {
        //try-with-resources per asegurar el tancament del stream
        try {
            int tamany = 6;
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

            for (int i = 0; i < tamany; i++){
                BigIntegerIO.writeBigInteger(new NumberGenerator().generateBigInteger(), dos);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Numeros aleatoris generats correctament!!\n");
    }

}
```

I have this method to split the file, but is not the correct way

```
public void splitFile() throws IOException {

    //Definir el tamany de les noves parts (tamany del file numeros.txt / 2)
    long fileSize = file.length();// 166,03 kB
    double sizeOfFiles = fileSize/2;// 83,01kB
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) sizeOfFiles +1];

    //Obtendre el nome de file sense ".txt"
    String fileName = file.getName();
    //String fileName = name.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");

    //Nombrar les parts 1, 2, ...
    int partCounter = 1;
    int cantitatBytes;
    //try-with-resources per asegurar el tancament del stream
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream bis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        while((cantitatBytes = bis.read(buffer)) > 0){
            //escriviu cada tros de dades en un fitxer separat amb un nombre diferent en nom
            String nomPartFitxer = String.format ("%s.%01d", fileName, partCounter++);
            File newFile = new File(nomPartFitxer);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            //try-with-resources per asegurar el tancament del stream
            try(DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos)){
                dos.write(buffer, 0, cantitatBytes);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: P.S: The methode generateRandomBigInteger() generate a file with 10.000 bigintegers

Comment: Have a look at this line: `dos.write(buffer, 0, cantitatBytes);`